# SPO Event Receiver is not firing

Tags: sharepoint-online, remote-event-receiver

Recently I am not able to create (remote) event receivers in my SPO environment(s).

- Create new site
- Create new list
- Add event receiver using PnP.PowerShell

```
Add-PnPEventReceiver -List "test" -Name test -Url "https://webhook.site/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" -EventReceiverType ItemAdded -Synchronization DefaultSynchronization
```

Nothing is triggered on the Listener. Tested on different tenants and with different listeners (webhooke.site and Azure Function). Does anyone else facing this issue?

Answer (score 2):

So, finally figured this one out. It seems like modern authetication is not supported when adding eventrecivers. So using legacy cookie based authentication when connecting using pnp (-UseWebLogin) and everything works fine.

I have not made a deep dive into the issue, so i can not tell if the issue is with PnP or SharePoint..

Comment: Confirming this issue still exists as of March 2022. Event Receivers get added, but do not fire. This solution worked for me.